# Hibernate update without select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I've a question on hibernate operation: update.

Here a bit of code:

```
Campaign campaign = campaignDAO.get(id);
campaign.setStatus(true);
campaignDAO.update(campaign);
```

If I just have all the data of the campaign object, is there any way to perform an update without performing the select (campaignDAO.get(id)) first?

Thanks,

Alessio

Comment: an update means you change something already existing, so you must retrieve it first, no doubt about it.

Comment: see this link :  [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1821095/1665377)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723528/hibernate-update-query-issue

Comment: @wxyz: That's not how SQL works. You can issue an update command without selecting first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HQL will definitely help you.

In order to maintain the separation of concerns, you can add a more specialized method in you DAO object:

```
public void updateStatusForId(long id, boolean status){
//provided you obtain a reference to your session object
session.createQuery("UPDATE Campaign SET status = " + status + " WHERE id = :id").setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
//flush your session
}
```

Then you could simply call this method from your business method. You can check the generated SQL statements inside the logs of your app by setting the `show_sql` hibernate property to `true`.

Comment: Is there another way to to this? I though the purpose of using Hibernate is because writing SQL in the code is a really bad apporach. It seems meaningless if we need to write HQL. In addition, involving logic in dao is also a bad approach, right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session.load(). It will not hit the database. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/) you can find its details and example code.

Comment: This does not work for me. The load part is correct but once the setter is applied it seems to go to the DB. The link you posted works for referential relationships but not for concrete properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had worte a extension to solve this issue in **Nhibernate**

***how to use!***
first of all you need enable ***dynamic-update="true"***

```
        using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            Customer c1 = new Customer();
            c1.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
            session.Mark(c1);
           // c1.Name = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            c1.Phone = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            //需要开启动态更新
            session.UpdateDirty(c1);
            session.Flush();
        }
```

***UpdateExtension.cs***

```
    public static class UpdateExtension
{
    static readonly Object NOTNULL = new Object();

    public static void UpdateDirty<TEntity>(this ISession session, TEntity entity)
    {
        SessionImpl implementor = session as SessionImpl;
        EntityEntry entry = implementor.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(entity);

        if (entry == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("找不到对应的实例，请先使用Mask方法标记");
        }

        IEntityPersister persister = entry.Persister;

        // 如果某列不可以为空，新的Entity里也不想更新他。
        // 那么LoadState 里的值应该和Entity 中的值相同

        Object[] CurrentState = entry.Persister.GetPropertyValues(entity, EntityMode.Poco);
        Object[] LoadedState = entry.LoadedState;

        int[] dirtys = persister.FindDirty(CurrentState
            , LoadedState
            , entity
            , (SessionImpl)session);

        if (dirtys == null || dirtys.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        persister.Update(entry.Id
            , CurrentState
            , dirtys
            , true
            , LoadedState
            , entry.Version
            , entity
            , entry.RowId
            , (SessionImpl)session);

        implementor.PersistenceContext.RemoveEntry(entity);
        implementor.PersistenceContext.RemoveEntity(entry.EntityKey);


        session.Lock(entity, LockMode.None);
         // 防止(implementor.PersistenceContext.EntityEntries.Count == 0)


    }


    public static void Mark<TEntity>(this ISession session, TEntity entity)
    {

        session.Lock(entity, LockMode.None);

    }
}
```

**here is update sql**

command 0:UPDATE Customers SET Phone = @p0 WHERE CustomerID = @p1;@p0 = '2014/12/26 0:12:56' [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]

***Only update Phone column .***

***event Name property can not be null. we can work very well.***